# Why "option" tags are not shown in React

Tags: reactjs

I start to learn React nowdays.
So my knowledge is poor.
I made a simple select-option website.
It shows country and language which I choose.
It has 2 select components and 2 labels that show country and language

Here is my code:

**DropDown.js**

```
import React from "react";

function Dropdown({ options, labelText, onChange }) {
  console.log(options);
  return (
    <div className="elementSet">
      <select data-testid="dropdown" onChange={onChange}>
        <option value={options} key={labelText} disabled>{labelText}</option>
        {options.map((value) => {
          <option value={value}>
            {value}
          </option>
        })}

      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Dropdown from "./DropDown";

const title = "Employee Information";

function App() {

    const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState('');

    return (
        <div>
            <h8k-navbar header={title}></h8k-navbar>
            <div className="layout-row align-items-centre justify-content-center mt-50">
                <section className="layout-column">
                    <div data-testid="country-options">
                        <Dropdown options={countryOptions} labelText={'Select Country'} onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)} />
                    </div >
                    <div data-testid="language-options">
                        <Dropdown options={languageOptions} labelText={'Select Language'} onChange={(e) => setLanguage(e.target.value)} />
                    </div>
                    <label className="mt-50 text-align-center">
                        Final Selections:
                    </label>
                    <label className="mt-10 finalText" data-testid="country-selected">
                        Country Selected: {`${country}`}
                    </label>
                    <label className="mt-10 finalText" data-testid="language-selected">
                        Language Selected: {`${language}`}
                    </label>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const countryOptions = [
    'USA',
    'Germany',
    'France',
    'Canada',
    'India',
    'Poland',
    'Japan',
    'Spain',
    'Australia'
];

const languageOptions = [
    'English',
    'Spanish',
    'French',
    'German'
]

export default App;
```

When I click the "Select Country", I expect that there are 9 options list such as 'USA', 'Germany', 'France', 'Canada', 'India' ...

But there is no option tags.

Why? And How to correct it?

I want to build correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return`:

```
 {options.map((value, i) => {
      return <option value={value} key={i}>
        {value}
      </option>
    })}
```

or without `return`:

```
{options.map((value, i) => (
      <option value={value} key={i}>
        {value}
      </option>
    ))}
```

Also, don't forget to add `key` prop.